# Get bytes from sqlite3 database before python 3.11

Tags: python, sqlite, apache-spark, pyspark

Im using pyspark and in an UDF create a sqlite3 db. However, the executors should not interact with the filesystem as it will cause transfer to the driver.

So I'm using

```py
conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE ...")
c.executemany("INSERT INTO ...")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

If I'd use a local `.db` instead of `:memory:` I can now send the bytes through network. However, how can I access the bytes representing the content with `:memory:`?